# discord.py invites - approximate_presence_count API gradually becomes slower

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

**TL/DR:**  I'm querying an invite link's `approximate_presence_count` every 10 seconds, and it gradually stops detecting presence changes over a very long period. How can I fix this?

### Goal

I'm writing a discord bot which monitors the number of online (and other statuses) members in several large (>100 members) servers I'm a member of. The bot is not a member of any of the relevant servers, and should log the number of members every 10 seconds or so.

This is not an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I do not want the bot to be a member of the servers, and simply just want it to use `approximate_presence_count` from invite links.

### Method

To do this, I've made permanent invite links to each of the servers, and I query their `approximate_presence_count` at 10-second intervals via a `tasks.loop`, logging those values to a text file.

Additionally, I have a small testing server in which I have several friends who log on and off, to test whether the member count is working.

All intents are enabled in the developer portal. This is not an intents-related issue.

### Problem

During testing on my small testing server, whilst running the bot over approximately a 24-hour period, I noticed that it becomes slower and slower to detect changes in `approximate_presence_count` after one of my friends logs on or off discord. I've reproduced this on several different days. While there is some minor variation in the time for `approximate_presence_count` to update at any given time, presumably due to the discord backend having variable amounts of load, this trend is constant.

After about 20-24 hours, the `approximate_presence_count` becomes almost useless, rarely detecting any changes.

**Expected result:** Delay between logon/logoff and change in `approximate_presence_count` remains constant

**Actual result:** Delay between logon/logoff and change in `approximate_presence_count` gradually increases

### What I've tried

In addition to the code below, I also tried not fetching the invites every single time `logger` loops, but this also did not work.

I can reproduce the info on more than one network, and on more than one machine.

### Minimal reproducible example

The code below is extracted from the bot and should be only the relevant components. There may be mistakes in the extraction process, but the gist remains the same.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks

TOKEN='removed'
INTENTS=discord.Intents.all()
links=['discord.gg/foobarbaz','discord.gg/fillertext']#real invites removed

client = discord.Client(intents=INTENTS)

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def logger():
  invites=[await client.fetch_invite(i,with_counts=True)for i in links]#invite objects
  counts=[getattr(i,'approximate_presence_count')for i in invites]#presence counts
  
  with open('logs.txt','a') as file:
    file.write(datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S ")+','.join(map(str,counts))+'\n')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  logger.start()

client.run(TOKEN)
```

#### Final notes

##### The expected delay in `approximate_presence_count`

In my testing when this issue does not occur, the delay between logon/logoff and the change in `approximate_presence_count` is between 5 and 40 seconds, with perhaps 1 in 100 being up to 60 seconds.

##### Number of invites tracked

The bot is tracking 6 invite links currently, so the frequency of requests to Discord is 0.6/second on average. Is this enough to cause a ratelimit, perhaps? **As EricJin mentioned in the comments, this is unlikely.**

Comment: I feel like you could blame caching. Just because you used fetch to get the invite doesn't mean you automatically fetch all the users as well. To confirm this, you can constantly watch over a small guild and fetch details of a few users every few seconds to see if their presences changed. Also: don't put `logger.start()` in `on_ready`. It could be called multiple times (see [docs here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_ready)). And no, if you popped ratelimits, it would definitely follow a more "structured" pattern, like each one taking 5 seconds exactly.

Comment: @EricJin I thought caching would make sense too, but then why does the caching gradually take longer and longer? In the actual bot, logger.start is only called once, but for the sake of brevity I just stuck it in on_ready for this minimal example. As I mentioned under "the expected delay" heading, there is some delay due to caching, but it's not very significant compared to this effect.

Comment: That's a good point. Have you tried it with the guild object just to see what happens with that? When you're in the guild, you can try `fetch_member`ing every member every few minutes and seeing if that updates anything. (I know this is not what your question is asking, it's just trying to narrow down the cause)

Comment: The problem has inexplicably disappeared for today. It's done this in the past, so I'll return to this question when I can reproduce it. Stay tuned!

Comment: Fetching the members has no effect.

Comment: I just fixed my local version of this code and am trying to fully reproduce this right now. I'll need at least a day to get any results, sorry! From what I see right now, the `approximate_presence_count` can be off by a *huge* margin, for example that returning 50, but a manual count of every member returning 40. Does it randomly fluctuate like it does for mine? Do you mind sending logs of the presence counts and how they change over time at the beginning (when it is normal) and when it starts breaking?

Comment: No problem about the time delay - `approximate_presence_count` doesn't seem to be that far off for me at all. Is it possible there's a large number of invisible users in that server who could be throwing off the presence count, since they are counted as presences too? I'll write a script to create the logs, but I'll also need a day or so.

Comment: Here's the correct, normal output, sampled every 10 seconds for just over 6 hours https://pastebin.com/raw/xmWSMXs2

Comment: That definitely seems slow. Mine has been going for almost 10 hours, and it is updating very quickly (although that might be because my testing guild has more members) https://paste.gg/p/greateric/4c5f6b360555430ab0ec2e95a1c1dbae

Comment: My testing guild only has six members, which is probably a contributing factor. I'll sample a larger guild (~300 members) tonight.

Comment: Also, I'm almost certain that the discrepancy you can see in your numbers is due to invisible users - I encountered this issue originally, and by switching statuses and checking the documentation was able to confirm that invisible users are included in `approximate_presence_count`. It appears 5 users are invisible in the server you tested in.

Comment: I found that the presence count does increase rapidly. I was querying once every 30 seconds to 1 minute on average. Even during midnight (in EST) where most people would be offline, it was very quick to detect changes and it fluctuated every few minutes.

Comment: It's been going strong for more than 2 days now. Still close to no difference, and changes are often detected immediately (fluctuating only after 1-2 checks).

Comment: The issue has also disappeared for me over that time period. I've got over 1/4 of a megabyte of presence count logs, and the issue isn't occurring at all. Given that neither of us experienced it during this time period, maybe the issue is on discord's end?

Comment: I would say so. Same bot is still going strong. It checks every minute and the invite's approximate precense count changes almost every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an issue on Discord's end as suggested in the comments. They have [changed how their invites work](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/208866998-Invites-101). This includes how permanent invite links work. While the article doesn't state the internal changes, it does state how the new invites work on the actual app/site. The time of change to the invites lines up to about when this post was made (May 2022) but has had updates since.

It seems you may have run into an issue that was present when these changes were made, which seems to be fixed at least at the time of posting this answer.

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't be surprised if this was indeed the issue. Thank you for checking this question. It's mostly been fixed now, though there is still a small delay.